# QuickSort Error Using First element as pivot

Tags: java

I have the following questions regarding my implementation of the code for the QuickSort Algorithm using the first element as the pivot always.

I have 2 sample files for my work and it seems that it does not work when given certain input. There appears to be a `StackOverflowError` on my recursion.

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there something I'm missing out?

Input that work will be random integers x10000.
Input that will have error will be number 10000 - 1 in a decreasing manner.

Both inputs are via text files seperated by `\n`.

```
public void quickSortOne(Integer [] arr)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = arr.length-1;

    quickSort1(arr, first, last);
}

public void quickSort1(Integer [] arr, int first, int last)
{


    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return;

    if (first >= last)
        return;

    //pick the pivot as first
    //int middle = first + (last - first) / 2;
    int pivot = arr[first];

    //make left < pivot and right > pivot
    int i = first, j = last;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
            q1Comparison++;
        }

        while (arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
            q1Comparison++;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
            q1DataMove++;
        }
    }

    //recursively sort two sub parts
    if (first < j)
        quickSort1(arr, first, j);

    if (last > i)
        quickSort1(arr, i, last);
}
```

Comment: The code looks okay. Where have you defined q1Comarison and q1DataMove? Did you try running it with small set of input data?

Comment: i've tried your suggestion and place the input in small set, from 0-5000 input it is working well. after 5000 i tried 7.5k and 10k inputs and it went haywire. giving the same overflow error again. q1Comparison and q1DataMove is just a int counter for other parts of the program and should not affect the run time.

Comment: I have posted a solution. I still think global variables like q1Comparison and q1DataMove are of no use in this recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of thread stack size due to default limit set by its OS. Especially for windows its very less (64KB).

Try running your app using below setting ->

```
java -Xss:512k myApp
```

You may also increase it to 1M or higher if needed. Here is the link to more info. Search for "Xss" on this page. ->

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

Hope this helps!